# If cells contains text along with numeric values, how can I remove the text from the cell?

Tags: excel

I am trying to prepare an excel file for import into another software program.  The data was originally converted from a text file.  The problem is that certain cells with dates or numeric values contain unwanted text, `"DELIM"`.  Since I have many rows of data that contains this text, I am trying to create an IF statement to remove the text from the cell.  Below is a formula that I have tried, but it is not working:

```
IF(ISNUMBER)SEARCH("*DELIM*")), "TRUE(DELETE "DELIM")
```

Is there an IF statement that can be used to delete the unwanted text from the cell?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"DELIM","")` will delete the exact text "DELIM" (case sensitive) from the text in `A1`.

If it's a one-time job, it might be easier to use search-and-replace (ctrl-h). If what you want to do is more complex, you may want to process the text file first in a another tool - probably one that offers regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried using this formula.  However, it deletes all contents in the cell when the cell contains "DELIM".  Since the cell also contains numeric values, I only want to delete the text and not the other values.  I also tried using Search-and-replace; however, this does not work well since each cell has unique values.  Is there another formula that can be used?

Comment: @taxmasster Something is being not understood.  If A1 is:  DELIM12345, the SUBSTITUTE formula given will return:  12345  If that is not what you want, provide a better example.  If that IS what you want, and the formula is returning nothing, then your data setup has not been adequately described.

Comment: Your understanding is correct.  I only want to delete the text from the cell, and the numeric values should remain.  However, the SUBSTITUTE formula described above resulted in a value of zero in the cell.  I decided to try your other suggestion using the Find/Replace Function and was able to get this to work.  I left the Replace value blank, and this deleted the text and left the remaining values in the cell.

Comment: @taxmasster Glad you got it to work.  The SUBSTITUTE should be leaving the numbers as a string and, depending on what you are doing with them, you may need to convert them to a "number" by performing some mathematical operation, such as adding zero; multiplying by one; preceding with a double unary; etc.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this instead:
=IF(SEARCH("DELIM",A1)="VALUE!",A1,SUBSTITUTE(A1,"DELIM",""))

the above code searches for the string "DELIM" if it finds it replaces with ""
else it will replicate the same string.